# Best combination choosing one team each round given some constraints

Tags: algorithm, math

## Problem

I have a table of sports results and am looking for the best possible way to select one team in each round such that the sum of the associated scores is maximal. This selection is subject to the following constraints:

- There are just as many teams as there are rounds
- You must select each team once and only once, and make only a single selection every round
- Some teams will not be a legal choice in some of the rounds

## Details

The score for a particular team in a particular round is the margin of the game they played in. It is positive if they have won and negative if they have lost

There are two possible reasons why a given selection may forbidden. The opponent of the lowest-ranking team (which may change between rounds) may never be selected. And in some games there may be byes, where the affected teams may not be selected either.

## Example

Consider the following example where the numbers in brackets are the scores for that team that round and the `*` denotes the team who is playing the bottom placed team and is therefore unavailable to be selected that round.

```
Round 1: Team A* (+26) vs Team B  (-26), Team C  (-15) vs Team D  (+15)
Round 2: Team A  (+75) vs Team C  (-75), Team B  (+ 5) vs Team D* (- 5)
Round 3: Team A  (+85) vs Team D  (-85), Team B* (- 3) vs Team C  (+ 3)
Round 4: Team A  (  0) vs Team B  (  0), Team C  (+12) vs Team D* (-12)
```

In this case the best combination would be to select:

1. Round 1: D (+15)
2. Round 2: B (+5)
3. Round 3: A (+85)
4. Round 4: C (+12)

Note: The example that I have created does not include any rounds with byes. It also doesn't require selecting a negative score for the best possible total, although this could obviously be possible.

## Known solution

Obviously with low numbers of teams or rounds you could brute force this by trying every combination. Is there a way to work this out for larger numbers of teams and rounds (say 20?).

Comment: Could you rephrase your problem in a simpler way (that is, pure math, no teams and sports references), or is it really this complicated? I have no clue what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to find the best combination of selections through this grid such that you can only tip one item per coloumn and per row.

http://i.imgur.com/46mqqaM.png

Comment: I've had a stab at editing this question, to get it off hold. Please check whether you still feel like this is the question you want to ask. And feel free to edit in any further improvements you can think of. If my edit should be completely wrong, feel also free to revert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically describing an [assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem): you are looking for a perfect matching between teams and rounds such that the sum of scores associated with the edges of the matching is maximized. The forbidden bottom teams can be modeled using a socre of -∞. The [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) is an established method for solving this kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks MvG. Your answer is exactly what I needed to figure out the problem.

I can't seem to select your answer though as the question is on hold.

Comment: @Danny: in that case, I suggest you update your answer so it is clearer. Then it can get reopened and be a valuable contribution. Particularly with the general formulation of the assignment problem in your mind you should be able to find a shorter and more generic formulation.